# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, regression

I'm new to Deep Learning. I have randomly generated datasets with following shape 
(5,4,4). 
It's something like

> [[[1 2 3 4]   [4 5 6 7]   [7 8 9 10]]]

I don't know why is it giving problem related to dimensions

My Keras code is given below

```
X_train=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5,4,4))
Y_train=np.random.rand(5,1)
X_valid=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2,4,4)
Y_valid=np.random.rand(2,1)

def create_model():
    nb_filters=2
    nb_conv=2
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2d(nb_filters,nb_conv,padding='same',input_shape=(4,4)
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    ****Other layers****
    enter code here
    model.add(Dense(1)
    model.add(Activation('linear')
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adadelta())
    return model
model=create_model()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train, batch_size=2,nb_epoch=50,verbos=1, validation_data=(X_valid,Y_valid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input data is missing the channel dimension (see [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added channel dimension but it's giving an error stating negative dimension size caused by subtrating 2 from 1 for 'conv2d_d/convolution' (op: Conv2D) with input shapes: [?,1,4,1],[2,2,1,1].
I added the channel dimension in input data like this

`X_train=X_train.reshape(10,1,4,4)`  
**(Channel first)**

Comment: By default `Convolution2d ` assumes that channels are in the last dimension. Try to specify `data_format='channels_first'` for this layer or change your data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time . Issue got resolved